# Silencing all console messages in openwrt

Tags: openwrt, u-boot

I am using ar93xx board with pepe2k u-boot. I need to silence all messages printed on the console, as I found there are separate parts print on console:

1- u-boot - can be silenced via its sources

2- early kernel messages starts with something like [0.000000] Linux version x.x.x - ??????

3- later kernel messages - can be silenced via sysctl.conf

4- login - silenced via inittab

My problem is number 2. I tried different ways but with no result, here is the list of some options I tried:

- disabling early printk in ar71xx/configxxx
- changing CONFIG_CMDLINE="rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd console=null" in ar71xx/configxxx
- change bootargs in uboot, console=null
- Make uboot with --silence option

none of them was useful, I got confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the point number 3 above (_later kernel messages_), how were you able to silence them? I have tried changing `kernel.printk` to no avail. I always see those lines in the output of `logread`. I'm on OpenWrt 21.02 (kernel version 5.4).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing quiet on the kernel command line.